# Facebook API Authentication PHP token stored in SESSION

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to authenticate users by logging in in their facebook account. 
I am able to get an access token which I save on my $_SESSION variable and get the information I need.
My problem is that, when I go to facebook and log in with a different account, the information that I get is from the first account. The application in this case is supposed to ask me to log in again (since I logged out from my facebook and logged in as a different user) but instead it is not and returns info about the first account. I guess my problem is that I store the token in my session which is the same the next time but how do I solve this?

```
$app_id = '...';
$app_secret = '....';
$redirect_url='...';

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id, $app_secret);

// Define Facebook's login helper and redirect back to our page.
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( $redirect_url );

// Check to ensure our session was started correctly and the access token exists.
if ( isset( $_SESSION ) && isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) ) {
  // Using the access token, create a new session.
  $session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );

  // Determine if the defined session is indeed valid.
  if ( !$session->validate() ) {
    $session = null;
  }
}
// Check if an active session exists.
if ( !isset( $session ) || $session === null ) {
 // If no session exists, let's try to create one.
 $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
 }

// Make sure we have a session started.
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
    // Save the session
    $_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();

   // Create a new Facebook session using our token.
   $session = new FacebookSession( $session->getToken() );
   echo 'Connected to Facebook!';
  } else {
   // Show login url
        echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'email', 'user_friends') ) .     '">Login</a>';
}
```

Comment: so your php code logs into facebook, from wherever it's running. and then you go directly to facebook and log in as someone else there? How would your php app know anything at all about what you're doing on your browser at home?

Comment: Hi Marc, yes I understand the problem but how do I check if the user is logged in? I tried destroying the session but that's not the solution as I always need to click log in.

Comment: do you HAVE to use PHP for the authorization? the javascript sdk is so much easier to handle.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I think I will go with JS then. However it would be nice to see a nice PHP implementation.